# How to interact with Photoshop application in Mac OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos, photoshop

I want to write a little app that interacts with Photoshop. I need only to set the foreground and background colors in Photoshop from my application.

I know that this is possible because applications like Tangerine are able to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Scripting Bridge`.

> [Scripting Bridge](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptingBridgeConcepts/Introduction/Introduction.html) is a framework and a technology that makes it much
>   easier for Cocoa developers to control and communicate with scriptable
>   applications.